# Equal height between two block in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs. How can I make them equal if the other div height adjust. I want all my divs to adjust its height even though they have less contents. Like in the image even the div without data must be equal to others and set the read more at the bottom.

link: http://www.psyc.org.sa/ar/

CSS

```css
.content_web_home {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

    .cont_right {
        float: right;
        width: 633px;
    }

    .cont_left {
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
    } 


<div class="content_web_home">

<div class="cont_right"></div>
<div class="cont_left"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Either use JavaScript, or table cells.

Comment: @Blazemonger JavaScript

Comment: BTW: custom style .css always after the bootstrap .css libary...

Answer (score 3):

```
parent { display: table; }
children {display: table-cell;}
```

And don't use float, use text align with inline-block or inline-block.

Comment: It's an example.  Your `.cont_right` and `.cont_left` elements are *children* and they must have a parent element.

Comment: content_web_home is the parent and cont_right and cont_left are children because they are inside content_web_home.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".cont_right").css('height', $(".cont_left").height() + "px");
```

This way the height of the `.cont_right` gets set to the same height of the `.cont_left`.
Just to insure that nothing gets messed I would work with `#id` instead of classes if you gonna use JS.

Comment: If there's a pure CSS solution available, there's no reason to consider using JS for this task.

Comment: sure I agree with you, but look at the thread comments... JS is called.

Comment: are you mean like `<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cont_right").css('height', $(".cont_left").height() + "px");
});
</script>` i will try bt not work

Comment: Maybe switch the classes? `$(".cont_left").css('height', $(".cont_right").height() + "px");` This just a dirty solution. You should really stick to the css.